# Wildfly port offset not working with Arquillain

Tags: jboss7.x, testng, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-8

Up until now I've been running my intergration tests using JBOSS AS 7 managed with Arquillian Testing framework. I have been setting the offset by 100 This has been working fine but now I want to transfer my integration tests to Wildfly AS managed but the same tests fail with the following error:

> arquillianBeforeSuite(com.aeroflex.teravm.selfinstall.core.ejb.SampleServiceIT)  Time elapsed: 130.749 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container

Here is my Arquillian.xml

```
   <arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<!-- <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.1"/> -->
<container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
<configuration>
<property name="jbossHome">target/wildfly-8.0.0.Final</property>
<property name="serverConfig">standalone.xml</property>
<property name="outputToConsole">true</property>

<property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100</property>
</configuration>
</container>
</arquillian>
```

and a sample of one of the integration tests:

```
public class SampleServiceIT extends BaseServiceIT
{
    @Inject
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @Parameters(ARQUILLIAN_DATA_PROVIDER)
    @Test(groups = {"integration"})
    public void testGetNotExisting() throws ServiceException
    {
        Long id = new Long(5);
        SampleBean result = sampleService.getSampleObjectById(id);
        Assert.assertNull(result);
    }
}
```

If I don't change the port offset and just leave the defaults it works fine.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: That looks odd, any chance you can provide fully reproducible case?

Comment: I solved the problem in the end... I was missing the managementPort property. <property name="managementPort">10090</property>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was missing the managementPort property which needs to be set.

```
<property name="managementPort">10090</property>
```

Full arquillian.xml file:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.1"/> -->
    <container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">target/wildfly-8.0.0.Final</property>
            <property name="serverConfig">standalone.xml</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>

            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100</property>
            <property name="managementPort">10090</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 1):

If some of you are running Arquillian tests like this through maven and you're using an embedded container, the `javaVmArguments` in the arquillian.xml will be ignored.

You need to the set the JVM arguments in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300</argLine>
         <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
         </systemPropertyVariables>

        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

NOTE: This is the configuration for the maven-failsafe-plugin (i.e., if your tests are *IT.java).  If your Arquillian tests are *Test.java, you'll want to configure the maven-surefireplugin.